# Js with git handle control version with the new module system client side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git

I see that the world change and everybody include my self is working with module system like common js in the client side.
In all the tutorials and blog posts i see the method is to have one file that we import all the other files to him.

So for example my project is written in angular js and the files looks like this:

//about/index.js

```
import AboutController from './aboutController.js';
import aboutDirective from './aboutDirective.js';

export default (app) => {
  app.controller('AboutController', AboutController);
  app.directive('about', aboutDirective);
}
```

//Main.js:

```
import modules from './modules';
const app = angular.module('name', modules);

import About from './components/about';
About(app);
```

So every feature will be added to this file and will pass the app to it.

**My question** is when every person in my team works on other feature and added this feature to this **Main.js** file, we will always get conflicts when push this code to git.

What is the solution to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is more about git then javascript. But me and my colleagues use this workflow to prevent/solve the conflict:
1) commit: first of all commit you modify so you cannot lose that.
2) Sync your project: by a fetch you see the difference and the conflicts
3) Resolve the conflict: we resolve the conflict manually, when you have resolve it, and you have choose the mod to keep or discard you make another commit. If you decide to take all the repos modifies you can "add to index" your file changed, then you commit again.

We always resolve the conflicts in that way, how to prevent it? you will have a conflict in the moments that someone modify your same file and:
1) the same rows: there is no way you don't have to follow the workflow above
2) not the same rows: in this case, if you have commit before the fetch you'll not have.
hope be of somekind of help.

Comment: This usually happens to me when developers change the same line and they are not fetch/committing code often enough. All code repositories say "Update often - Commit often".